# robin herbot's inputmask with commas and 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Robin Herbot's inputmask jquery plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), and I am getting output as expected but I want it with commas i.e. 12,345.67 and with 2 decimals.

```
$('#currency').inputmask({'mask':"9{0,10}[.9{0,2}]", greedy: false});
```

Answer (score 9):

I have managed to make it working with following code

```
$('#currency').inputmask({
   'alias':          'decimal',
   'groupSeparator': ',',
   'autoGroup':      true, 
   'digits':         2,
   'digitsOptional': false,
   'placeholder':    '0.00'
});
```

so the actual output looks like this
`12,312,311.00`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks kukic but Before decimal I want to allow only 6 digits and when I have placeholder; ' ' I have dot seen which should not be shown.

Comment: digitsOptional set to true fixes dot which is not shown now. But not able to figure how to allow only 6 digits before decimal.

Comment: @nain try adding max 999999

Comment: @Nain you can set input maxLenth `<input type="text" maxlength="10">` property and apply mask as it is

Comment: kukic adding maxlength="10" will allow them to enter all 10 digits but i want to limit only to 6 digits.

Comment: kukic where should I add max 999999 ?

Comment: @Nain here is an example of min and max values defined [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/Iluaam/)